# stream-state-metrics bytes-written-total is always 0

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

kafka_streams_stream_state_metrics_bytes_written_rate is always 0 in my case. But i see kafka_streams_stream_rocksdb_state_metrics_put_total reflecting the total number of records. What may be the reason? I tried to set the Statistics in options through rocksdb.config.setter class and then it works. I am using kafka-streams-2.4.0. In addition to setting the metrics.recording.level to debug do i need to do anything to make the RocksDBMetricsRecorder to record Statistics ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you hit a known bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9675

It's fixed already but the fix is not released yet. You can either build from the corresponding branches yourself to get the fix, or you need to wait until 2.4.2, 2.5.1, or 2.6.0 is released.